# Run Clean-up Logic on Docker Container's Shutdown/Killing?

Tags: linux, bash, docker, shutdown

Given:

- Host machine
- Docker container running web service

I'd like to implement "clean-up" logic upon the shutdown of the web service. It seems to me that there's 2 ways to do this:

### 1. [On Dockerfile's `ENTRYPOINT`] Use `trap` per the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/)

```
trap "echo TRAPed signal" HUP INT QUIT KILL TERM

/usr/sbin/apachectl start
```

### 2. **[On Host]** Use `docker events` ...

Run `docker events`, filtering on `die` or `shutdown` (see [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/events/)) until I see my container's hash. Then run my clean-up logic when such an event occurs (example: via `bash` script`)

### Concerns/Questions

I know little about Linux's `SIGNAL`'s, as well as how processes handle such SIGNALs. So, I'm not sure if it's possible in some scenarios for the clean-up logic to not be called.

In short, I'm curious of the best way to ensure that my clean-up script runs upon the shutdown/killing of a docker container.

Comment: you should read https://medium.com/@gchudnov/trapping-signals-in-docker-containers-7a57fdda7d86#.b8lb7rfrp

Comment: The docker [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) show: `trap "echo TRAPed signal" HUP INT QUIT KILL TERM`. Is that invalid due to a trap of `KILL` per the blog post's [note](https://medium.com/@gchudnov/trapping-signals-in-docker-containers-7a57fdda7d86#.ssantpa8k): `All signals except for SIGKILL and SIGSTOP can be intercepted by the process.`